# How to redirect to external url with Javascript after function return true

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, redirect

I am ab beginner with javascript and I have checked a lot of post regarding that topic but till now I haven't find a answer for that. So I would be glad if anybody could help me with this task:

I have a form with an input tag for a partner number which the user shall enter. After click on the submit button the function checkNumber is activated. When the entered partner number is not true then an alert shall be shown. When the partner number is no true then the user is forwarded to an external URL from us. It should be the first step of an Login Check.

So far so good. I have written the form and the function to check the partner number (see below-mentioned code). But How can I redirect the user to the external URL after the partner number check return true?
I have tried with window.location.replace and window.location.href but then the complete

I would be really happy if anybody could help me.

```
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>login</title>

<!-- Validation of entered value -->
<script>
function checkNumber(form)
{
var partnernr = form.partnernr.value;
var regex1 = /^[0-9]{6}?$/;
var regex2 = /^[0-9]{5,6}(\+|-|\/)[0-9]{1}?$/;
if(!regex1.test(partnernr))
{
if (!regex2.test(partnernr))
{
alert('Your partner number is not valid.');
form.partnernr.focus();
return false;
}
}
return true;
}
window.location.replace = 'https://www.xyz.de'
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkNumber(this)">

<input type="text" name="partnernr" placeholder="e.g. 600000 / 600000-1"" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="ikbsendbutton postidentbutton" value="Start POSTIDENT-Method"  />

</form>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Do you want to submit the form, or do you want to redirect the user?  The user can't be directed to two different requests at the same time...

Comment: It is like a login. When the user enters the correct partner number / password the user is forwarded to an exclusive website. Otherwise the user gets the message that the password is not correct.

Comment: Ok, in that case... Do you want to submit the form, or do you want to redirect the user in JavaScript?  These are two very different actions.  If you don't want to submit a form then overall it'll probably be easier to remove the `<form>` entirely.  Then you don't have to worry about *canceling* the form submit event, since there isn't one to cancel.  You can just perform the logic you want and redirect the user.

Comment: Hmm, yes that would be the easiest way. But the first check is neccessary because in the url is a specific id included which is neccessary for the ident check: /identportal/wl?an=50350947113703&rn=PA

Answer (score 0):

The code `window.location.href = "https://google.com"` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have tried the additional script at the end of the body tag and also already location.href. But when I enter a partner number no redirection happens.

Comment: window.location.href = "https://google.com" is working but immediately when open the url. But I would like to have the redirect after the user has entered a valid partner id.

Comment: create a function and call it when you want to redirect:
`
function go(url) {
  window.location.href = url
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to prevent the default submit behavior and then redirect to a new page if your check function is successful.

You can add a new script tag to the bottom of your body (so the DOM gets parsed and you can grab the form element), then prevent the default submit behavior and redirect if your check passes.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>login</title>

    <!-- Validation of entered value -->
    <script>
        function checkNumber(form) {
            var partnernr = form.partnernr.value;
            var regex1 = /^[0-9]{6}?$/;
            var regex2 = /^[0-9]{5,6}(\+|-|\/)[0-9]{1}?$/;
            if (!regex1.test(partnernr)) {
                if (!regex2.test(partnernr)) {
                    alert('Your partner number is not valid.');
                    form.partnernr.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="my-form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="partnernr" placeholder="e.g. 600000 / 600000-1" />
        <input type=" submit" name="submit" class="ikbsendbutton postidentbutton" value="Start POSTIDENT-Method" />
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (checkNumber(e.target)) {
                window.location.href = 'https://www.xyz.de'
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```